# C# Web API Data Model from SQL returns duplicated rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

I have a Web API 2.0 application that interacts with an SQL database back end.  It is connecting to a view that did not have a primary key and thus Visual Studio would not create the entity in edmx file.  So I adjusted the view to create a primary on the fly.  Here is the view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(tr.id, - 999) AS MyPrimaryID, CASE WHEN [Date] IS NOT NULL THEN [Date] ELSE tr.shipmentDate END AS Date, dt.message AS Status, dt.Location, 'THIS' + RIGHT(tr.trackingNum, LEN(tr.trackingNum) - 3)AS Tracking FROM dbo.tblTrackingDetail AS dt LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.tblTracking AS tr ON dt.idLink = tr.id
```

The view works just fine inside of SQL.  My main search criteria is the trackingNum column.

```
SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[vTracking] where tracking = 'THIS123456'
```

That query returns the following:

[image]

After creating my ADO.NET Entity Data Model I have the file vTracking.cs under my edmx file.  Here are the contents:

```
namespace MyServices.Models{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class vTracking
{
    public int MyPrimaryID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Tracking { get; set; }
}
```

}

Under my Controllers folder I have TrackingController.cs containing the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MyServices.Models;

namespace MyServices.Controllers
{
public class TrackingController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<vTracking> Get()
    {
        using (MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities())
        {
            return dbContext.vTrackings.ToList();
        }
    }
    //public vTracking Get(string id)
    public IEnumerable<vTracking> Get(string id)
    {
        using (MyEntities dbContext = new MyEntities())
        {
            return dbContext.vTrackings.Where(e => e.Tracking == id).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now when I run this it basically takes the first line returned from the SQL results screenshot and duplicates that data four times.

[image]

At first, I assumed the problem lied with the controller file and how I coded for passing the tracking ID.  But as I was troubleshooting the problem I realized that if I simply went to http://localhost:60850/api/tracking/ and not include a tracking number, meaning it returns every tracking number, then the results on that page showed the same thing.  The first line of data repeated 4 times as well as the same type of pattern for the other sets of data.  So I think the problem actually lies in the Data Model files but nothing I have tried has yielded the same results as a simple SQL select statement to the SQL view.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It’s probably because you don’t have unique id in your view, it messes EF up, add some newid() in your view as an extra column and into your edmx and it should fix things.

Comment: I tried adding the extra column with newid() but it yielded no different result.  Still giving me the first row several times only now it has the newid() column.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I take that back. Your solution did work but I needed to add one extra step.  In the EDMX file, I had to designate the column with the newid() as the entity key from the EDMX diagram screen.  After taking your advice and redesignating the entity key it worked!